# EJB Exception in Jboss

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, ejb

I have deployed the web application in jboss. For Sometime it works fine but after that i get the EJB exception and hence couldn't create the connection. So I have to restart the jboss server time to time.

Here is the stacktrace.

```
 10:10:23,584 ERROR [LogInterceptor] EJBException in method: public abstract   java.lang.String np.com.wdn.remit.validator.UserValidator.getAgentCode(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception:
javax.ejb.EJBException: Application Error: no concurrent calls on stateful beans
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatefulSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatefulSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:304)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
    at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:954)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invoke(BaseLocalProxyFactory.java:430)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.StatefulSessionProxy.invoke(StatefulSessionProxy.java:79)
    at $Proxy60.getAgentCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp.login(index_jsp.java:344)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:599)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at           org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

10:10:23,586 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp.login(index_jsp.java:444)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:599)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
10:10:32,427 ERROR [STDERR] org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ); - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ))
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:94)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at np.com.wdn.remit.common.Global.makeConnection(Global.java:54)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at np.com.wdn.remit.transaction.RemitTransactionBean.isTxnPaid(RemitTransactionBean.java:3242)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at np.com.wdn.remit.transaction.RemitTransactionBean.getSearchResult(RemitTransactionBean.java:2496)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359)
10:10:32,428 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.server.ServiceEndpointInterceptor.invoke(ServiceEndpointInterceptor.java:64)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.java:173)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorBMT.invoke(TxInterceptorBMT.java:77)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:169)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:136)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:954)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invoke(BaseLocalProxyFactory.java:430)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.StatelessSessionProxy.invoke(StatelessSessionProxy.java:103)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy62.getSearchResult(Unknown Source)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jsp.reports.reportdetails_jsp._jspService(reportdetails_jsp.java:877)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
10:10:32,429 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
10:10:32,430 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
10:10:32,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
10:10:32,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
10:10:32,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
10:10:32,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
10:10:32,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
10:10:32,431 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

10:10:32,436 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: Unable to connect to database. No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ); - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: No ManagedConnections available within configured blocking timeout ( 30000 [ms] ))
10:10:32,436 ERROR [STDERR]     at np.com.wdn.remit.common.Global.makeConnection(Global.java:61)
10:10:32,436 ERROR [STDERR]     at np.com.wdn.remit.transaction.RemitTransactionBean.isTxnPaid(RemitTransactionBean.java:3242)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at np.com.wdn.remit.transaction.RemitTransactionBean.getSearchResult(RemitTransactionBean.java:2496)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.server.ServiceEndpointInterceptor.invoke(ServiceEndpointInterceptor.java:64)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.CallValidationInterceptor.invoke(CallValidationInterceptor.java:63)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptor.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptor.java:121)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.invokeNext(AbstractTxInterceptorBMT.java:173)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.TxInterceptorBMT.invoke(TxInterceptorBMT.java:77)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionInstanceInterceptor.java:169)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:168)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.LogInterceptor.invoke(LogInterceptor.java:205)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.invoke(ProxyFactoryFinderInterceptor.java:136)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.SessionContainer.internalInvoke(SessionContainer.java:648)
10:10:32,437 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.Container.invoke(Container.java:954)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.BaseLocalProxyFactory.invoke(BaseLocalProxyFactory.java:430)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.local.StatelessSessionProxy.invoke(StatelessSessionProxy.java:103)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy62.getSearchResult(Unknown Source)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jsp.reports.reportdetails_jsp._jspService(reportdetails_jsp.java:877)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
10:10:32,438 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:524)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
10:10:32,439 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is this the jboss error or application error? Please help me soon. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD.

Actually, JBoss prohibited concurrent calls to stateful beans, that's what you get here.

Check similar question here - [EJB3 stateful concurrent calls from different clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001740/ejb3-stateful-concurrent-calls-from-different-clients)

Comment: The SQLException appears only after ejb exception is encountered. Before that it works fine.